# Angular: ¿Cómo obtener intervalo entre un rango de horas con Moment.js?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, momentjs, schedule

necesito su ayuda:

Resulta que de una api recibo un objeto con un rango de horas segun el lugar:

```
affiliate{
   "attentionSchedules": [
            {
              "room": "200",
              "floor": 2,
              "schedules": [
                            {
                         "days": [
                            "MO",
                            "TU",
                            "FR",
                            "TH",
                            "WE"
                         ],
               "_id": "x",
                "initialTimeStr": "07:00 am",
                "finalTimeStr": "04:00 pm",
                "initialTime": "2020-11-12T13:00:00.000Z",
                "finalTime": "2020-11-12T22:00:00.000Z"
}
],
   "place": {
    "loc": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": []
},
"_id": "x",
"name": "Hospital x",
"address": "x"
    }
   }
  ]
 }
```

Del anterior objeto initialTimeStr y finalTimeStr, es mi rango de horas, por ejemplo va algo asi:

El usuario A, atiende en tres lugares y de esos tres lugares tiene distintos horarios de atención. Lo que yo quiero hacer es que cuando el usuario seleccione "X" lugar, se filtren las horas de acuerdo al luhar y a su vez se obtenga el recorrido del intervalo entre ese rango de horas. A modo que el resultado sea algo asi:

[image: horas]

Como se muestra en la imagen el intervalo sería de una hora:
7:00 AM - 8:00 AM ..... - 5:00 PM

Actualmente esto es lo que tengo:

Utilizo la libreria Moment-Range para obtener un rango entre ambos y compararlas

```
//Variable donde pretendo almacenar el rango de horas
timeList: string[] = [];

// Mapeo el objeto para obtener la hora de inicio y almaceno en variable start
this.start = this.bookingService.bookingModel.affiliate?.attentionSchedules.map(schedule => schedule.schedules.map(initialTimeStr => initialTimeStr.initialTimeStr));
console.log('start', this.start);
//Mapeo el objeto para obtener la hora de inicio y almaceno en variable end
this.end = this.bookingService.bookingModel.affiliate?.attentionSchedules.map(schedule => schedule.schedules.map(finalTimeStr => finalTimeStr.finalTimeStr) );
console.log('end', this.end);
//Formateo las horas
let start = moment(this.start, "HH:mm");
let end = moment(this.end, "HH:mm");
//let diff = end.subtract(start);

console.log('let start', start);
console.log('let end', end);
//intento obtener el rango
let rangoHoras = momentRange.range(start, end);

//rango start y end
rangoHoras.start.format('HH:mm');
rangoHoras.end.format('HH:mm');

console.log('range start', start);
console.log('range', rangoHoras);

//  this.selectedPlace = this.bookingService.bookingModel.affiliate?.attentionSchedules.filter(schedule => schedule.place._id === this.addressID)
console.log('hourEnd :>>', this.bookingService.bookingModel.affiliate?.attentionSchedules.map(schedule => schedule.schedules.map(finalTimeStr => finalTimeStr.finalTimeStr)));

//Si ha seleccionado el lugar
if(this.selectedPlace){
  console.log('hourStart :>>', this.bookingService.bookingModel.affiliate?.attentionSchedules.map(schedule => schedule.schedules.map(initialTimeStr => initialTimeStr.initialTimeStr)));
}

//Metodo que llena la iteracion
  setTime(time: string) {
    this.selectedTime = time;

   // let start = moment()

    //this.convertToDatetime();
  }
```

Y en el html tengo lo siguiente:

```html
  <div class="col-12" *ngIf="selectedDate" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-anchor-placement="top-bottom">
                    <div class="mb-1 px-4">
                        <h4 class="primaryText fw-bold m-0">Selecciona hora</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 mx-4">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div *ngIf="selectedDate" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-anchor-placement="top-bottom" class="DateContainer ms-4">
                            <!-- Slider main container -->
                            <swiper [config]='swiperConfig' (swiper)="onSwiper($event)" (slideChange)="onSlideChange()">
                                <ng-template swiperSlide class="SwiperItem text-center" *ngFor="let time of timeList; let i = index">

                                    <button *ngIf="selectedTime == time" mat-flat-button color='primary' class="SelectedTime" class="btn">{{time}}
                                    </button>
                                    <button *ngIf="selectedTime != time" mat-stroked-button (click)="setTime(time)" class="btn">{{time}}
                                    </button>
                                </ng-template>
                            </swiper>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Realmente lo he intentado, pero no lo he logrado y ya no se que hacer, porfavor ayuda, trate de detallar, muchas gracias de antemano. Soy algo nueva programando, una ayuda, una guía, algo le estare muy agradecida

Comment: Hola!. El problema se ve bastante enredoso. Te propongo un método más ordenado para resolverlo. Primero. Aísla el código que no te funcione y haz un ejemplo funcional en https://stackblitz.com. Una pregunta, es necesario usar moment? Luxon es una alternativa un tanto ligera, con soporte de types para el ide, es posible que lo cambies?

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, hice otra pregunta ya con lo que probe, lo que no puedo hacer ahora es mostrar en pantalla las horas que ya filtre por rango:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/502336/angular-c%c3%b3mo-puedo-filtrar-un-rango-de-horas-por-dias