# Angular: ¿Cómo puedo filtrar un rango de horas por dias?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, schedule

Tengo la siguiente peticion que me trae un objeto:

```
 getAvailability(date: any) {
    this.bookingService.getAffiliateAvailability(this.doctor?.id, this.addressID, date)
    .subscribe(res => {
        this.availability = res;
        const { slots } = this.availability;
        this.slots = slots;
        console.log(slots);
        this.getSchedulOptions();
       //this.changeDate(slots);
      }, (error => {
        console.error(error)
      }))
    }
```

Dentro de este tengo un metodo que me obtiene el rango de las horas:

```
getSchedulOptions() {
    let hours: any[] = [];
    this.slots.forEach((s: any) => {
      let disable;
      //console.log('s', s);
      let start = new Date(s.start);
      //console.log('probando start', start);
      let end = new Date(s.end);
      //console.log('probando end', end);
      let range = this.getrange(start, end);
      hours= hours.concat(range);
      
    })
    console.log('customRange', hours);
  }

  getrange = (start: Date, end: Date) => {
    let startDateInteger = start.getHours();
    let endDateInteger = end.getHours();
    let hours = [];
    // hours.push(this.integerAsDateString(startDateInteger));
    for (let i = startDateInteger; i < endDateInteger+1; i++) {
      let tempDate =new Date(start);
      tempDate.setHours(i); 
      hours.push(tempDate);
    }
    return hours;
  }

  integerAsDateString = (num: number) => {
    return num + ":00"
  }
```

Este es el resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Y tengo un evento que evalua el cuando se ha seleccionado un dia en un calendario

```
changeDate = (date: any) => {
    console.log('date :>> ', date);
    this.bookingService.bookingModel.appointmentDate = date;
    if(date){
      this.timeList = this.getAvailability(date);
      console.log('timeList', this.timeList); 
    }

  }
```

Y recorro el timeList en el html:

```html
<div *ngIf="selectedDate" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-anchor-placement="top-bottom" class="DateContainer py-2 d-flex">
  <!-- Slider main container -->
  <mat-icon class="swiperLeft m-auto">chevron_left</mat-icon>
  <swiper class="TimeContainer" [config]='swiperConfig' (swiper)="onSwiper($event)" (slideChange)="onSlideChange()">
    <ng-template swiperSlide class="SwiperItem text-center" *ngFor="let time of timeList; let i = index">

      <button *ngIf="selectedTime == time" mat-flat-button color='primary' class="SelectedTime">{{time}}
                                        </button>
      <button *ngIf="selectedTime != time" mat-stroked-button (click)="setTime(time)">{{time}}
                                        </button>
    </ng-template>
  </swiper>

  <mat-icon class="swiperRight m-auto">chevron_right</mat-icon>
</div>
```

Actualmente no me muestra nada, pero practicamente quiero que una vez he seleccionado el dia el rango de horas que filtro en getSchedulOptions se itere sin repeticiones y se recorra con el ngFor. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo? Si ya he filtrado y obtenido el rango ¿ahora como lo muestro en pantalla? Ayuda, porfavor. Quiero lograr algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo qué quieres filtrar las horas, luego de eso, según los resultados quieres tener una lista de horas sin repeticiones?

Si es así, puedes usar Set para agrupar las horas de tu array filtrado. Eso te dará una lista nueva sin repeticiones.

Comment: Por favor no uses el area de respuestas para comentar, si no tienes la reputación suficiente para hacerlo intenta responder preguntas para obtener la reputación necesaria. De paso lee [answer]